# Python Py2app error

Tags: python, linux, py2app

I ran into problem while using py2app on Fedora 18:

```
running py2app
creating /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/python2.7-semi_standalone/app
creating /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/collect
creating /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/python2.7-semi_standalone/app/Frameworks
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
*** using recipe: email ***
*** filtering dependencies ***
351 total
342 filtered
0 orphaned
9 remaining
*** create binaries ***
*** byte compile python files ***
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py to pkg_resources.pyc
*** creating application bundle: do_it ***
skipping byte-compilation of /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/dist/do_it.app/Contents/Resources/site.py to site.pyc
copying do_it.py -> /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/dist/do_it.app/Contents/Resources
creating /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/dist/do_it.app/Contents/Resources/lib
creating /run/media/vik2015/D0DD-6FB2/MacEdit/dist/do_it.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7
error: Operation not permitted
```

If it helps, here is my **`setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['do_it.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': [],}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And **`do_it.py`**

```
import os
os.system("python program.py")
```

Comment: You realize that `py2app` is designed for building Mac OS X app bundles on OS X, not on linux?

Comment: Is it?.. Ohh, I thought I can use it on any platform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cross platform platform builded from Python, try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

We use it successfully with Windows and Linux, but we are having one `.spec` file for the windows build machine and a slightly different one for the Linux build machine. The advantage of having the same tool for building both on Linux and Windows is that we can have a set of common functions for the two.

As we are distributing our application also on Mac, we are also using `py2app`, but on a dedicated Mac Osx build machine.